# How to add custom parameter to fabric js object in a way that is preserved when the fabricCanvas is serialized to file

Tags: fabricjs

I have trouble to add custom parameter to fabric-js object.

I create a circle object:

```
var circleShape = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 100,
  fill: '#eef',
  scaleY: 0.5,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});
```

I add a custom parameter:

```
circleShape.set("customParam", 'foo' );
```

I serialize the circle object to json, and verify that the customParam is part of the json:

```
var circleShapeAsJson = circleShape.toJSON(['customParam']);
console.log("circleShapeAsJson" + circleShapeAsJson);
```

I add the circle object to the fabricCanvas:

```
fabricCanvas.add(circleShape);
```

I can see in chrome debugger, that the custom variable is part of the child object in the fabricCanvas in `fabricCanvas._objects[1].`

But if I stringify the fabricCanvas, I no longer see the custom parameter:

```
let fabricCanvasAsStr = JSON.stringify(fabricCanvas);
console.log('fabricCanvasAsStr', fabricCanvasAsStr);
```

What do I need to do, to add a custom parameter so that it can be serialized to file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This post seems to solve my problem: https://groups.google.com/g/fabricjs/c/dHVoTbj0MU0
i.e.
call

```
let fabricCanvasAsJson = COL.model.fabricCanvas.toJSON(['customParam']);
this.annotationAsJsonStr = JSON.stringify(fabricCanvasAsJson);
```

instead of

```
this.annotationAsJsonStr = JSON.stringify(COL.model.fabricCanvas);
```

when serializing to file.